# Visual Code JavaScript Intellisense Type Casting

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

It's possible to have intellisense in visual code (https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_intellisense) and that's wonderful.

I'm working with angularjs. Services are injected and no intelisense is available for that. So there my question is, is it possible to cast variables so that i can have intelisense? I think comments in javascript can be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally possible to have intellisense with Visual Studio Code.

But if you're working with AngularJs and not Angular2, you might have `.js` files instead of `.ts`.

So if you want to have a better support for AngularJs within VSC, first I'd recommend you to use this definition file : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/angularjs

Then, of course, you'll need to type your code otherwise only the AngularJs core system will be typed.

You might want to learn more about Typescript [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/).